# Make ImageView Circular

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, xamarin

I have an ImageView which I am attempting to make Circular in Xamarin. This would be simple enough and I would have done it with Core Animation, but the images are being downloaded Asynchronously like this:

```
this.profileImage.InvokeOnMainThread (() => this.profileImage.SetImage (
    url: new NSUrl (datum.user.profile_picture)
    )
);
```

How would I make these images circular?

Comment: Did you try to use `Border` ?

Comment: No How would I use that in this context? @Babak.Abad

Comment: Do you have access to CALayers in Xamarin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is How I ended Up fixing my issue:

```
this.profileImage.InvokeOnMainThread (() => this.profileImage.SetImage (
            url: new NSUrl (datum.user.profile_picture)
        )
    );

// Make Image Profile Image Circular
CALayer profileImageCircle = profileImage.Layer;
profileImageCircle.CornerRadius = 30;
profileImageCircle.MasksToBounds = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

Following this - Late to the party but can be helpful

** Using OP's Code to make the application more generic as to make any image - regardless of size, circular **

```
this.profileImage.InvokeOnMainThread (() => this.profileImage.SetImage (
            url: new NSUrl (datum.user.profile_picture)
        )
    );

// Make Image Profile Image Circular
CALayer profileImageCircle = profileImage.Layer;
profileImageCircle.CornerRadius = profileImageCircle.Frame.Size.Width / 2;
profileImageCircle.MasksToBounds = true;
```

By Adding "profileImageCircle.Frame.Size.Width / 2;" we will get the radius needed for the image we are using, so that it will always be circular - assuming it is a square image.

Comment: You can't convert an nFloat into a CALayer. You might need to amend that code slightly.

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.Layer.CornerRadius = imageView.Frame.Size.Width / 2;
imageView.ClipsToBounds = true;
```